# error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol - but symbol is not used in project

Tags: c++

I've been getting this really weird error;

> MyClassFile.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol "void * __cdecl CreateDescriptor(unsigned long)" (?CreateDescriptor@@...) [C:\path-to-my-project\myProject.vcxproj]

The thing is when I search my project for this symbol name it is not anywhere in there!

Now, I have been changing where some of the functions in my project are included from, and while the symbol referred to in the error message is not one I've moved it is in the same file as some I did. So I thought maybe my solution is in a bad state so I cleaned and rebuilt each project but I still get this error.

Anyone got any ideas on how a symbol which is not used in a project could cause an 'unresolved symbol' error when building that project?

Comment: You don't need it but what if one of the libraries you use needs it?

Comment: Likely it's used indirectly, even if not explicitly.